# Which HTTP Module calls the ASP.NET MVC Action Filters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Which ASP.NET `HttpModule` is responsible for calling the action filters registered within an ASP.NET MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be done not by HttpModule, but by `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker` class, used by  `Controller` class to invoke action methods.
There is decompiled code of `ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction` method, calling filter methods

```
public virtual bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName) && !controllerContext.RouteData.HasDirectRouteMatch())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "actionName");
        }
        ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = this.GetControllerDescriptor(controllerContext);
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = this.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);
        if (actionDescriptor != null)
        {
            FilterInfo filters = this.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
            try
            {
                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = this.InvokeAuthenticationFilters(controllerContext, filters.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor);
                if (authenticationContext.Result != null)
                {
                    AuthenticationChallengeContext authenticationChallengeContext = this.InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext, filters.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, authenticationContext.Result);
                    this.InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, authenticationChallengeContext.Result ?? authenticationContext.Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = this.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(controllerContext, filters.AuthorizationFilters, actionDescriptor);
                    if (authorizationContext.Result != null)
                    {
                        AuthenticationChallengeContext authenticationChallengeContext2 = this.InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext, filters.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, authorizationContext.Result);
                        this.InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, authenticationChallengeContext2.Result ?? authorizationContext.Result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest)
                        {
                            ControllerActionInvoker.ValidateRequest(controllerContext);
                        }
                        IDictionary<string, object> parameterValues = this.GetParameterValues(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
                        ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext = this.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filters.ActionFilters, actionDescriptor, parameterValues);
                        AuthenticationChallengeContext authenticationChallengeContext3 = this.InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext, filters.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, actionExecutedContext.Result);
                        this.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(controllerContext, filters.ResultFilters, authenticationChallengeContext3.Result ?? actionExecutedContext.Result);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ExceptionContext exceptionContext = this.InvokeExceptionFilters(controllerContext, filters.ExceptionFilters, exception);
                if (!exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                this.InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, exceptionContext.Result);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've had a cursory look and will have a closer look in a few hours. At a first glance, I can't seem to find the place where any *custom* action filters I write might be invoked. This seems to do a drill of invoking a fixed sequence of the inbuilt ones.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Got back to this subject today and after studying the code you mentioned in Reflector, I see that the custom action filters (and the inbuilt ones, are all being loaded into a `FilterInfo` class instance through which they are available and) are being called just after the request validation, in the line `ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext = this.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filters.ActionFilters, actionDescriptor, parameterValues);`. Thank you. :-)